# Mule runtime manager agent support for Community edition

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

Can someone share the key-features available in Mule-3.9 release cut of Community edition like wrapper enhancement.

Any idea that runtime-manager agent can be used in 3.9 community version?

Answer (score 1):

This link gives detailed info about fixes and enhancements in Community edition of Mule 3.9.Check "Community Edition Enhancement Request" section.

[Mule Runtime 3.9.0 Release Notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-3.9.0-release-notes)

The Runtime Manager is only available for Enterprise versions of Mule runtime, not for Community versions. Currently, the Runtime Manager Agent supports Mule 3.6.0 or later.As per below link

[The Runtime Manager Agent](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-agent)